# pyfacebook doesn't have set_status in that object anymore?

Tags: python, pyfacebook

i just try this

```
import facebook
fb = facebook.Facebook('YOUR_API_KEY', 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY')
fb.auth.createToken()
fb.login()
fb.auth.getSession()
fb.set_status('Checking out StackOverFlow.com')
```

and got this

```
gunslinger@c0debreaker:~$ python Python 2.6.2 (release26-maint, Apr 19 2009, 01:56:41)  [GCC 4.3.3] on linux2 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import facebook
>>> fb = facebook.Facebook('MY_API_KEY', 'MY_SECRET_KEY')
>>> fb.auth.createToken() u'SECRET'
>>> fb.login()
>>> fb.auth.getSession() Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/facebook/__init__.py", line 670, in getSession
       File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/facebook/__init__.py", line 1123, in __call__
       File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/facebook/__init__.py", line 1056, in _parse_response
       File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/facebook/__init__.py", line 1007, in _check_error
     facebook.FacebookError: Error 100: Invalid parameter
>>> fb.set_status('Checking out StackOverFlow.com') Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> AttributeError: 'Facebook' object has no attribute 'set_status'
>>>
```

pyfacebook remove set_status() function in newest pyfacebook ?

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the [source code](http://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/blob/master/facebook/__init__.py), it looks like you need to use fb.status.set()

Comment: well i'll keep trying i just use that and give me facebook.FacebookError: Error 250: Updating status requires the extended permission status_update by the way thanks for info

Comment: i've already solve the problem check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849624/update-status-facebook-using-python thanks