# Update status Facebook using Python

Tags: python, facebook, status, pyfacebook

I'm trying the solve problem update status using facebook API with `pyfacebook`. So I look at here [Update Facebook Page's status using pyfacebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907662/update-facebook-pages-status-using-pyfacebook) and I think doesn't work anymore.

Well, finally I solve the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import facebook
# Replace these with your app's credentials
api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
secret_key = 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY'
client = facebook.Facebook(api_key, secret_key)
client.auth.createToken()
client.login()
print '[*] Please login / give permission application to access you . Then press enter key to continue...',
raw_input()
try:
    client.auth.getSession()
    client.request_extended_permission("publish_stream", popup=False)
    raw_input()   
    cek = client.status.set("Testing update status using facebook API with pyfacebook")
except facebook.FacebookError, e:
    print "ERROR", e
```

Comment: i'm not ask just share what i solve, hope it's help if some people need

Comment: Thank you for sharing information. but this is not how you share information. if you would like to share information. Please post the problem as a question. then answer your own question and mark it as answered so people can use this post as a reference.
please make the right changes as this will just clutter stackoverflow.com thank you once again though for sharing your information as its people like you that make the programming world go round.
PK