# Facebook status update using pyfacebook 

Tags: python, facebook, pyfacebook

[Update status Facebook using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849624/update-status-facebook-using-python)
I am using this answer to solve my problem. 
But this thing asks to authenticate the app , that is ok. But every time I run the script it again opens the browser .. what I want is to post it silently without opening the browser once I have given all the permissions to the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyFacebook is deprecated. Use the new Oauth REST Api.

Comment: Yep, this is the way... just make sure you store the oauth token that Facebook gives you.